# How to (temporarily) stop Elasticsearch from expunging deleted documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

In [my usecase](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-elasticsync) I'm trying to synchronize two Elasticsearch indices. Due to versioning this is acutally [quite simple](https://github.com/Aconex/scrutineer). However, I want to keep writing at any time while I'm doing this.

Okay, so the steps I want to perform in chronological order:

1. clients write (index, delete, update) to cluster c1
2. create a new index c2 (clients keep writing to c1)
3. copy data from cluster c1 to c2 (clients keep writing to c1)
4. switch clients to c2
5. synchronize changes from c1 to c2 (clients keep writing to c2)
6. shutdown c1

Step #5 is the step I'm currently looking at. I have to make sure that changes written to c2 aren't overwritten by data from c1. Using versioning it's rather simple for writes as index operations will fail (VersionConflictEngineException). Assuming the following situation:

1. a document is updated on c1 right after #3 (v2 on c1, v1 on c2)
2. the same document is deleted right after #4 (v2 on c1, deleted on c2)
3. synchronizing will try to reindex v2 on c2

I know that elasticsearch keeps deleted documents around for a while:

```
# index document 1:4
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/test/1?version=4&version_type=external' -d '{"message": "test"}'
{"ok":true,"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":4}

# delete document 1:6
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test/test/1?version=6&version_type=external'
{"ok":true,"found":true,"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":6}

# index document 1:4 (ERROR!)
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/test/1?version=4&version_type=external' -d '{"message": "test"}'
{"error":"VersionConflictEngineException[[test][2] [test][1]: version conflict, current [6], provided [4]]","status":409}

# wait some time

# index document 1:4 (SUCCESS!)
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/test/1?version=4&version_type=external' -d '{"message": "test"}'
{"ok":true,"_index":"test","_type":"test","_id":"1","_version":4}
```

The problem clearly is the "wait some time" part. I will have to rely on the deleted documents for an unknown amount of time. Therefore I need to control this time by disallowing any expunging of deleted documents while I'm running #5. How would you do this?

*Crossposted to [Elasticsearch group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/IU0b09LYs98/Z8ysJe9wdmEJ) (and this [related question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elasticsearch/aclwWeLe4rU/jBjiKLzmv4IJ))*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "wait some time" part is defined by `index.gc_deletes` setting on per index basis and set to "60s" by default. It can be dynamically changed using [Update Index Settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings/) command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems though, that dynamically changing this setting is broken. The corresponding field in code is `org.elasticsearch.index.engine.robin.RobinEngine.gcDeletesInMillis` which is only modified after a previous info log `"updating index.gc_deletes from [{}] to [{}]"`. This line never gets logged though.

Comment: Do you know whether this settings is reliable? Could documents be expunged due to optimization/merging before the index.gc_deletes time expires?

Comment: It is pretty reliable. The versions of deleted documents are kept independent of segments and therefore unaffected by merging. The only scenario that I can think of when it might be possible to expunge version prematurely involves moving shards between nodes faster than index.gc_deletes timeout.